# Where is "ildasm" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ildasm

I used to be able to run `ildasm` in the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2017. With Visual Studio 2019, `ildasm` is no longer available:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>ildasm
'ildasm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Was it replaced with something else or is my VS 2019 installation incomplete?

Comment: [See also](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/474677/vs2019-developer-command-prompt-still-using-net-46.html).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I updated VS 2019 to version 16.2 and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`ildasm.exe` is installed with the Windows SDK tools, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\ildasm.exe` or somewhere similar depending on the version.

You can install the SDK from [this website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) or by selecting it in the optional components during the installation of VS2019.

Comment: I spend hours looking for ILDASM today. Thanks you very much!

Comment: In Visual Studio installer, Workloads tab, the Windows 10 SDK is included in Universal Windows Platform Development.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use it directly from Developer Command Prompt 2019/2017

Comment: That works in VS2019, didn't have to install anything else.